Change chrome built-in search engine shortcut
I want to change the shortcuts for my chrome built-in search engines. As you can see in the picture below I have changed the bookmarks search from the default of @bookmarks to :b, however there is no longer a pencil icon on the right side of the bookmarks row. I want to modify the shortcut for the bookmarks again.
How do I do that?
I am using latest versions of chrome and brave on windows as of 2024/04/23

What have I tried so far?

Using grep on the userprofile folder to try and find keywords relating to these search engines, in the hope of finding a .js file with settings to edit, similar to firefox.
Googling how to change chrome search engines. (Every result is just how to use the gui to modify the user added search engines, not the built-ins like Bookmarks)
Searching stack overflow for similar questions. (I have not found anything relating to this problem)


I'm having the same issue.
This is a bug introduced as of Chromium M124. Link to bug tracker record below. I'd suggest you use the +1 on the upper right to indicate that you're impacted as well. This helps the devs prioritize items that need to be fixed.
https://issues.chromium.org/issues/333952131
